# Getting outer points of a polygon

Tags: java, 2d, region, polygons

I have 5 chunks and each chunk has 4 corners so that gives me 20 corners in total, however, not all of these corners are used to define the points of a 2D polygon region.

Edit: I have all of the 20 corners needed for the algorithm.

This is currently what I'm working with but please keep in mind the shape and number of chunks in the polygon may not always look like this.

[image: Sample Image]

The white crosses indicates where the points should be but we have no data for a starting point. Each chunk (represented via a blue cube) is 16x16 blocks. How would I go about creating an algorithm that'll find all the outer points needed to create a polygon region? I'm not the best at Maths either so sorry if I sound a bit nooby :P